# Different columns of the same name SQL Sorted by Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL

```
Category | Subcategory | Region | Count | Percent |
    A    |      Aa     |   ON   |   3   |   5%    |
    A    |      Aa     |   AT   |   1   |   2%    |
    A    |      Ab     |   ON   |   5   |   10%   |
    B    |      Bc     |   AT   |   1   |   21%   |
```

But I want to be able to make an SQL statement that'll give me the query like this

```
Category | Subcategory | Region | Count | Percent | Region | Count | Percent |
    A    |      Aa     |   AT   |   1   |   2%    |   ON   |   3   |   5%    |
    A    |      Ab     | NULL/0 | NULL/0|  NULL/0 |   ON   |   5   |  10%    |
    B    |      Bc     |   AT   |   1   |   21%   | NULL/0 | NULL/0|  NULL/0 |
```

Would this be possible to do in SQL as a either a select or a stored procedure?

Comment: possible - yes. a good idea? not so much. better use unique names for the query and change them in the presentation layer.

Comment: Unique names for each region? Because I was thinking of making a few queries with a  stored procedure for each region and then doing a join but I wasn't sure if that'd have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you should use unique column names. To achieve your desired output, you can use conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bce30/2/0)

```
SELECT
    Category,
    SubCategory,
    Region_AT = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'AT' THEN Region END),
    Count_AT = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'AT' THEN [Count] END),
    Percent_AT = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'AT' THEN [Percent] END),
    Region_ON = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'ON' THEN Region END),
    Count_ON = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'ON' THEN [Count] END),
    Percent_ON = MAX(CASE WHEN Region = 'ON' THEN [Percent] END)
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Category, SubCategory
```

---

If you do not know how many `Region`s are there, you can use dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bce30/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql2 NVARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql3 NVARCHAR(2000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    Category
    , SubCategory' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Region = ''' + Region + ''' THEN Region END) AS Region_' + Region + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Region = ''' + Region + ''' THEN [Count] END) AS Count_' + Region + CHAR(10) +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Region = ''' + Region + ''' THEN [Percent] END) AS Percent_' + Region + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT Region FROM Tbl
)t

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Category, SubCategory'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

You can read more about dynamic crosstab in this great [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) by Jeff Moden.

Comment: You sir are a god. This worked amazingly! Thank You!

Comment: Make sure to read the referenced article. It's an easy read and is very educational. =)